# Multiple sends through MessageDefinitionSends

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud

Is there currently a way to batch triggered send requests through the REST API? All I'm finding in the [documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/api/messaging-messagedefinitionsends-send) is triggering one at a time.

Code Sample (removing the array and only sending one element works as expected):

```
fuel({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:33/send',
        json: true,
        body: [{
                From:{
                    Address:"myFromAddress@domain.com",
                    Name:"David"
                },
                To:{
                    Address:"myemail_1@domain.com",
                    SubscriberKey:"myemail_1@domain.com",
                    ContactAttributes:{
                        SubscriberAttributes:{
                                CusField1:"My Custom Field 1",
                                CusField2:"My Custom Field 2",
                                CusField3:"My Custom Field 3"
                            }
                    }
                }
            },{
                From:{
                    Address:"myFromAddress@domain.com",
                    Name:"David"
                },
                To:{
                    Address:"myemail_2@domain.com",
                    SubscriberKey:"myemail_2@domain.com",
                        ContactAttributes:{
                            SubscriberAttributes:{
                                CusField1:"My Custom Field 1",
                                CusField2:"My Custom Field 2",
                                CusField3:"My Custom Field 3"
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }]  
    }, function (error, request, body) {
        console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(body));
    });
```

console: < response: {"message":"Problem initating message send during deserialization of JSON payload.","errorcode":10004,"documentation":""}

I have tried different variations of the above code like sending just the "To" section as an array and encapsulating the array in parent brackets.  I used fuel for ease of example, but the same error can be achieved in Postman.

Comment: since you have tried some code already - it would be helpful to provide the code, json and error you have received, so we can start from there.  The answer provided should work, but if you had an issue, it may be a problem with your JSON specifically.  the more details you can provide, the better. Thanks!

Comment: I just edited to include example utilizing fuel. I appreciate your help with this!

Comment: Your body json doesn't lint properly. Try adding the quotes to the keys.

Comment: Same response after quotes.

Comment: Did you start the message definition in the application? In other words - you can send one, but not multiple?

Comment: for the purposes of testing, I hard-coded the payload if that's what you are asking.  If I edit the payload to remove the array, it sends fine as well.  Am I using the correct url?? I ask because when I switched my dataevents to batches I had to change the url from row to rowset.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13115/discussion-between-kelly-j-andrews-and-david)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch them by sending in as an array to

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{your key}/sendBatch

[{
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Region": "West",
                "City": "Indianapolis",
                "State": "IN"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example2@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example2@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Region": "East",
                "City": "Indianapolis",
                "State": "IN"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: I tried this in postman yesterday before asking and got this:
{
    "message": "Problem initating message send during deserialization of JSON payload.",
    "errorcode": 10004,
    "documentation": ""
}

Comment: url path change was the fix! thanks for your help!

Comment: The recommended option for sending multiple emails using a single API requests through the Marketing Cloud would be to use the SOAP API.  The sendBatch option above is not documented.