# Fuel REST sendBatch

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, send-email, fuel

Is there an actual help/doc. page for the sendBatch endpoint?  I see folks reference the actual endpoint in various posts, and have successfully used it - but have not found a help/doc. page on it.

the endpoint I'm using is - 
[exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{Custom‌​Key}/sendBatch](http://exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:%7BCustom%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BKey%7D/sendBatch)

Answer (score 0):

This question asks the same thing and has an answer but not link to documentation:

[Multiple sends through MessageDefinitionSends](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28110/multiple-sends-through-messagedefinitionsends)

Are you speaking of the Messaging/Send Endpoint?

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/push/postMessageBatch.html

> The messageBatch resource allows you to send unique messages to
>   devices within the same API call. Each batch can include a maximum of
>   5000 subscriber key or device token values (depending on which value
>   the call uses).

All of the API documentation can be found [Here](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html)

The current documentation shows the endpoint of:

https://xxxx/push/v1/messageBatch/xxxx/send?access_token=xxxx

Does this do the same thing as your endpoint (maybe your endpoint is depreciated??)

If you could be specific about the endpoint we could be more exact with an answer

Comment: Sorry, to clarify - the endpoint I'm using is - "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{CustomKey}/sendBatch

Comment: Thanks for the input Eric - I'm specifically looking for TriggeredSend usage, as in - https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html - except that it can handle more than one Email

Comment: @user7934 - Right, the answer I have in my answer addresses it. There appears to be no documentation which may mean it is depreciated. I was just thinking that maybe the other endpoint I posted may be a replacement (or irrelevant).....This is all I could find but I am no Expert in ET so.....